# How to parse xml in tableviewcontroller in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

in application i have a xml tree
Root--->
     Subject--->
           SubjectID 1   /SubjectID
           SubjectName MatheMatics /SubjectName
                       Sub_Subject---->
                               Sub_SubjectID 1 /Sub_SubjectID
                               Sub_SubjectName Calculus /Sub_SubjectName
                       /Sub_Subject
                       Sub_Subject
                       Sub_SubjectID 2 /Sub_SubjectID
                       Sub_SubjectName Geometry /Sub_SubjectName
                       /Sub_Subject
      /Subject
      Subject---->
            SubjectID 2 /SubjectID
            SubjectName Physics /SubjectName
      /Subject
/Root

i want to store subject in one of table view & sub-subject store in another table view
how can i do it pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse an XML document using NSXMLParser and its delegate, NSXMLParserDelegate. You should also look into NSPropertyListSerialization too.

Comment: Hi.... David can you provide some sort of code where form i started thanks in advance......

Comment: Its better for you to read "Event-Driven XML Programming Guide". It's very detailed and will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser can be used for parsing XML files. You can google and you will defintely find sample codes.You can also try using TouchXML.

I just googled and  found this 
[link](http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/)

hopw this helps